# How to POST https request to execute Billing Agreement for Paypal using Java

Tags: java, paypal

While trying to post https request using Java to execute paypal billing agreement, I am getting 401 response. What's wrong I am doing in the request below.

```
String url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/" +request.getParameter("token") + "/agreement-execute";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"); 
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Execute Token : " + request.getParameter("token"));
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding how to connect via Java:

[This guide](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal) from paypal should walk you through the necessary steps

#### Regarding your error:

From [PayPal Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-error-handling/)

> Authentication Errors
> HTTP Status Code: 401
>
> Authentication errors are often caused by issues related to access tokens:
>
> - Ensure the access token is included and correct.
> - Ensure the access token hasn't expired.

Comment: How do I know access token is expired.

Comment: Try the [REST API Playground](https://devtools-paypal.com/hateoas/index.html?interactive=ON&env=sandbox)

Comment: Thanks Tim for providing reference to the REST API Playground link above. But, I could not find option for recurring billing using playground. Where, I can execute billing agreement.

Answer (score 0):

OK got it

There is an API provided by Paypal to use for executing billing agreement instead of Posting the URL directly.

The API provided is `Agreement.execute(apiContext, token);`

replace the code above with

```
    String token = request.getParameter("token");
    String accessToken;
    try {
        accessToken = GenerateAccessToken.getAccessToken();
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        Agreement.execute(apiContext, token);

        System.out.println(Agreement.getLastRequest());
        System.out.println(Agreement.getLastResponse());


    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```